# Can xcodebuild print which assertion/expectation exactly failed of a failing XCTest?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest, xcodebuild

When running Xcode unit tests from command line using `xcodebuild`, it will only print if a test succeeded or failed, like

> Test case '<...name...I>' passed on 'My Mac - xctest (75744)' (0.005 seconds) 
> Test case '<...name...>' failed on 'My Mac - xctest (75744)' (1.714 seconds)

but it won't tell me which test assertion or expectation exactly has failed.

When running the tests in Xcode, Xcode will halt the test and jump into the debugger, so I can see exactly the failing assertion or expectation. This is critical information as a test may have a dozen of different assertions and expectations and depending on which one is failing, there is a completely different problem.

Is there a way I can make `xcodebuild` print the assertion text or at least print the line number of failure?

Comment: Please include an example of the simplest failing test you can make that does this. Are you using XCTest assertions? Or is this from a thrown error?

Comment: @JonReid `XCTAssert(false);` Won't get simpler than that. Or `int i = 10; XCTAssertEqual(i, 20);` When running the later one in Xcode, I get `SimpleTests.m:20: error: -[SimpleTests justFail] : ((i) equal to (20)) failed: ("10") is not equal to ("20")` in the debugger console. When I run it with `xcodebuild test` and choosing the same workspace, scheme and build configuration as in the UI, I just get `Test case '-[SimpleTests justFail]' failed on 'My Mac - xctest (32958)' (0.001 seconds)`; that's all it outputs on either stdout or stderr.

Comment: Interesting. You are correct, with `XCTFail("hey")` I don't see the line number or even "hey" in the output of `xcodebuild test`.